# Assign seconds elapsed between subsequent index values to new column

Tags: python, pandas

Lets's say I have a Pandas dataframe where the index is a datetime value.  I want to add a column that is the calculation of the total_seconds elapsed between each subsequent record.

Problem setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ["2021-02-24 20:53:14.572000+00:00", "2362"],
        ["2021-02-24 21:02:28.567000+00:00", "4264"],
        ["2021-02-24 21:02:29.572000+00:00", "5160"],
        ["2021-02-24 21:02:30.561000+00:00", "6183"],
        ["2021-02-24 21:03:55.606000+00:00", "9654"],
    ],
    columns=["event_time", "some_metric"],
)

# Make the timestamp our index and make sure the events are in order.
df["event_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["event_time"])
df = df.set_index("event_time")
df = df.sort_index()
```

So now my dataframe looks like this:

```
                                 some_metric
                      event_time    
2021-02-24 20:53:14.572000+00:00    2362
2021-02-24 21:02:28.567000+00:00    4264
2021-02-24 21:02:29.572000+00:00    5160
2021-02-24 21:02:30.561000+00:00    6183
2021-02-24 21:03:55.606000+00:00    9654
```

Now I want to add a new column that is the seconds elapsed until the next event.

Here's what I'm trying, which runs without error::

```
df["seconds_until_next"] = (
    df.reset_index()["event_time"].shift(-1) - df.reset_index()["event_time"]
).dt.total_seconds()
```

But the resulting dataframe looks like this, with all NaNs in the new column:

```
                                 some_metric    seconds_until_next
                      event_time
2021-02-24 20:53:14.572000+00:00    2362              NaN
2021-02-24 21:02:28.567000+00:00    4264              NaN
2021-02-24 21:02:29.572000+00:00    5160              NaN
2021-02-24 21:02:30.561000+00:00    6183              NaN
2021-02-24 21:03:55.606000+00:00    9654              NaN
```

Which is weird, because just running the right side of that operation looks like it returns the values I want:

```
(df.reset_index()["event_time"].shift(-1) - df.reset_index()["event_time"]).dt.total_seconds()
```

returns:

```
0    553.995
1      1.005
2      0.989
3     85.045
4        NaN
Name: event_time, dtype: float64
```

What's going on here?  I assume it's because of a mismatch in index values between the df on the left side of the equals and the result on the right side?  How do I resolve that?

Update:
These answers are great, wish I could give everyone the points. I feel like the magic piece of knowledge I was missing was `.to_series()`. Will definitely keep the other suggestions in mind. This way works and feels good in my brain, not sure if it's the most performant:

```
df["seconds_until_next"] = (
    df.index.to_series().shift(-1) - df.index.to_series()
).dt.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar (but slightly more concise) option with `diff` (instead of `shift`ing and subtracting):

```
df['seconds_until_next'] = -df.index.to_series().diff(-1).dt.total_seconds()

df
```

Output:

```
                                 some_metric  seconds_until_next
event_time                                                      
2021-02-24 20:53:14.572000+00:00        2362             553.995
2021-02-24 21:02:28.567000+00:00        4264               1.005
2021-02-24 21:02:29.572000+00:00        5160               0.989
2021-02-24 21:02:30.561000+00:00        6183              85.045
2021-02-24 21:03:55.606000+00:00        9654                 NaN
```

Comment: This is neat.  So .diff() does BOTH the shift and the difference in one operation.  That actually seems like the right way to do what I'm doing, although understanding the utility of .to_series()  and why my original approach didn't work was probably the most important part of what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you do `reset_index`, you got a different index (RangeIndex) which doesn't align with the original `df` and you get all `NaN` values. Try `to_series`:

```
df['time_gap'] = df.index.to_series().shift(-1).sub(df.index).dt.total_seconds()
```

Output:

```
                                 some_metric  time_gap
event_time                                            
2021-02-24 20:53:14.572000+00:00        2362   553.995
2021-02-24 21:02:28.567000+00:00        4264     1.005
2021-02-24 21:02:29.572000+00:00        5160     0.989
2021-02-24 21:02:30.561000+00:00        6183    85.045
2021-02-24 21:03:55.606000+00:00        9654       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

There a subtle issue - will be a range index which does not match datetime index.  Worked around by making it an array with `.values`

```
df.assign(seconds_until_next=(pd.Series(df.index).shift(-1) - df.index).dt.total_seconds().values)
```

| event_time | some_metric | seconds_until_next |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-24 20:53:14.572000+00:00 | 2362 | 553.995 |
| 2021-02-24 21:02:28.567000+00:00 | 4264 | 1.005 |
| 2021-02-24 21:02:29.572000+00:00 | 5160 | 0.989 |
| 2021-02-24 21:02:30.561000+00:00 | 6183 | 85.045 |
| 2021-02-24 21:03:55.606000+00:00 | 9654 | nan |